# JAVA. Перебор комбинаций через else if. Нужно уменьшить код

Tags: java, алгоритм, if

есть константа;
пользователь вводит 5 значений;
если какое то(какие то) значения меньше константы, то алгоритм присваивает и возвращает уникальное число.
С объяснениями, всегда было плохо((( прощу прощения(((

```
public int Block(int push1,int  pull1, int sq1, int abc1, int sp1 ) 
{
        int res;
        int push = 30;
        if (push1< push) {
            pushConst=0;
        }
        int pull = 12;
        if (pull1< pull){
            pullConst=0;
        }
        int squat = 60;
        if (sq1< sq){
            sqConst=0;
        }
        int abc = 50;
        if (abc1< abc){
            abConst=0;
        }
        int sp = 50;
        if (sp1< sp){
            spConst =0;
        }

    if (pushConst==1&&pullConst==1&&sqConst==1&&abConst==1&& spConst ==1) {  
        res = 1;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&pullConst==1&&sqConst==1&&abcConst==1) {
        res = 2;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&sqConst==1&&abConst==1&& spConst ==1){
        res=3;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&pullConst==1&&abConst==1&& spConst ==1){
        res=4;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&pullConst==1&&sqConst==1&& spConst ==1){
        res=5;
    } else if (pullConst==1&&sqConst==1&&abConst==1&& spConst ==1){
        res=6;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&pullConst==1&&sqConst==1){
        res=7;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&sqConst==1&&abConst==1){
        res=8;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&pullConst==1&&abConst==1){
        res=9;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&pullConst==1&& spConst ==1){
        res=10;
    } else if (pullConst==1&&sqConst==1&&abConst==1) {
        res =11;
    } else if (pullConst==1&&abConst==1&& spConst ==1) {
        res=12;
    } else if (squatConst==1&&abConst==1&& spConst ==1){
        res = 13;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&sqConst==1&& spConst ==1){
        res = 14;
    } else if (pullConst==1&&sqConst==1&& spConst ==1){
        res=15;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&abConst==1&& spConst ==1) {
        res = 16;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&pullConst==1) {
        res = 17;
    } else if (pushConst==1&&sqConst==1) {
            res = 18;
    }else if (pushConst==1&&abConst==1) {
            res = 19;
    } else if (pushConst==1&& spConst ==1) {
            res = 20;
    } else if (pullConst==1&&sqConst==1) {
            res = 21;
    } else if (pullConst==1&&abConst==1) {
            res = 22;
    } else if (pullConst==1&& spConst ==1) {
            res = 23;
    } else if (sqConst==1&&abConst==1) {
            res = 24;
    } else if (sqConst==1&& spConst ==1) {
            res = 25;
    } else if (abConst==1&& spConst ==1) {
            res = 26;
    } else if (pushConst==1) {
        res = 27;
    }else if (pullConst==1) {
        res = 28;
    }else if (sqConst==1) {
        res = 29;
    }else if (abConst==1) {
        res = 30;
    }else if (spConst ==1) {
        res = 31;
    } else { 
        res = 32;
    }

    return res;
```

Comment: В чем ваш вопрос то? и помоему вы изобретаете битовые флаги своими условиями

Comment: надо уменьшить код(

Comment: Чтоб уменьшить код - нужно понимать что на входе и на выходе, нужна именно такая последовательность проверок или не важно? если использовать битовые флаги - можно получить инкрементарное число в зависимости от каждого из флагов всего одной строкой, но это число врятли совпадет с вашими

Comment: на входе произвольное число от 0 до 100;
последовательность не важна; на выходе, в зависимости от "res", выводится сообщение;

Comment: Не сходится с вашим кодом, вижу на вход 5 интов, а не один. если "порядок" чисел не важен - можно ваши условия сократить вот до такой строки ```return (pushConst==1 )<<4 + (pullConst==1)<<3 + (sqConst==1)<<2 + (bConst==1)<<1 + spConst==1```, возможно в яве придется кастовать типы, но это не точно(не уверен как работает bool и битовые операции), не исключено что порядок нужно поменять(цифра сразу за знаком << ), и так же не исключено что это будет избыточное кол-во выходных чисел... альтернатива - цикл, или вложенные условия

Comment: У вас в коде все эти переменные только обнуляются. А если обнуления нет, они чему равны?

Answer (score 3):

Как было отмечено в комментариях Владимиром Клыковым, входные значения `push1, pull1, sq1, ab1, sp1` переводятся в битовые флаги `xxxConst`, которые соответственно можно использовать для вычисления индекса в массиве, значения которого будут соответствовать нужным значениям `res`:

```
push pull sq ab sp  index  res
  1    1   1  1  1    31     1
  1    1   1  1  -    30     2
...
  1    -   -  -  -    16    27
  -    1   -  -  -     8    28
  -    -   1  -  -     4    29
  -    -   -  1  -     2    30
  -    -   -  -  1     1    31
  -    -   -  -  -     0    32
```

Таким образом можно будет полностью избавиться от операторов `if`.

```java
public static int blockNew(int push1, int pull1, int sq1, int abc1, int sp1) 
{
    int push = push1 < 30 ? 0 : 16;
    int pull = pull1 < 12 ? 0 : 8;
    int sq = sq1 < 60 ? 0 : 4;
    int ab = abc1 < 50 ? 0 : 2;
    int sp = sp1 < 50 ? 0 : 1;
    
    final int[] arr = {
        32, 31, 30, 26,  29, 25, 24, 13, //  0 ...  7
        28, 23, 22, 12,  21, 15, 11,  6, //  8 ... 15
        27, 20, 19, 16,  18, 14,  8,  3, // 16 ... 23
        17, 10,  9,  4,   7,  5,  2,  1  // 24 ... 31
    };

    return arr[push + pull + sq + ab + sp];
}
```

Элементарный тест для сравнения:

```java
int ok = 0;
int f = 0;
for (int push: new int[]{1, 30}) {
    for (int pull: new int[]{1, 12}) {
        for (int sq: new int[]{1, 60}) {
            for (int ab: new int[]{1, 50}) {
                for (int sp: new int[]{1, 50}) {
                    int r1 = Block(push, pull, sq, ab, sp);
                    int r2 = blockNew(push, pull, sq, ab, sp);
                
                    if (r1 == r2) {
                        ok++;
                    } else {
                        f++;
                        System.out.println("Diff: old=" + r1 + "; new=" + r2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Ok=" + ok + "; fails=" + f);
// -> Ok=32; fails=0
```